# Leaflet.ImageOverlay and zoom range

Tags: javascript, leaflet, zooming, layer

It appears to me that Leaflet.ImageOverlay does not have a minZoom and a maxZoom option like Leaflet.TileLayer has.  But I have a map image that I only want to be visible at two or three zoom leves.  Is there a cunning way to circumvent this issue?

I guess, I can use gdal2tiles.py or gdal_retile.py to create a file for a tile layer, but as I'm using UTM projection (Mercator gives a horrible distortion in Norway), I'm not sure what tile numbers makes my map image fit in with the background map.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `zoomend` event to conditionally hide/show your `L.ImageOverlay`.